# Read text file, then store lines in array to filter out certain strings

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, txt

I'm currently trying to read a text file, and store the lines in an array. I then try to filter out certain words with strstr. I'm getting no output when trying to print elements of the array, and the strstr function doesn't seem to work. Visual Studio is telling me that I'm using uninitialized memory in my lines pointer. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Format of the text file:

```
// comments should be ignored
 
//empty lines as well
<Name>Peter</Name>
<Name>Anna</Name>
<Age>16</Age>
<Pet>
<Race>Dog</Race>
<PetName>Lucky</Petname>
</Pet>
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char* c = "test1.txt";
    char s[500];

    char* lines[100];
    int sizelines = 0;

    printf("%s \n\n", c);

    FILE* myFile = NULL;
    myFile = fopen(c, "r");

    if (myFile != NULL) 
    {
        while (fgets(s, 500, myFile) != NULL) 
        {
            if (s[0] == '/') continue; // ignore lines that start with /
            if (s[0] == ' ') continue; // ignore lines that start with " "
            lines[sizelines] = malloc(50);
            lines[sizelines] = _strdup(s);

            sizelines++;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Wrong file");
    }

    fclose(myFile);

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(lines); i++)
    {
        if (!strcmp("<Name>", lines[i]))
        {
            const char* s = lines[i];

            const char* PATTERN1 = "<Name>";
            const char* PATTERN2 = "</Name>";

            char* target = NULL;
            char* start, * end;

            if (start = strstr(s, PATTERN1))
            {
                start += strlen(PATTERN1);
                if (end = strstr(start, PATTERN2))
                {
                    target = (char*)malloc(end - start + 1);
                    memcpy(target, start, end - start);
                    target[end - start] = '\0';
                }
            }

            if (target) printf("%s\n", target);

            free(target);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `strlen(lines)` is not how you find size of your lines array.  Why not use sizeliens?  The other option is to store a sentinal, like NULL, as the last element and iterate till you find it.  If the first part works, hard-code it.  Also your example doesn't compile due to "error code here". `strcmp("<Name>", lines[i]))` will never return true as none of your inputs contains "<Name>" and nothing else.

Comment: Please tag this with Windows something as you rely on a non-standard header file.  In turn this means I will ignore the question :-)

Comment: Which information from `<winsock2.h>` is your code actually using?  I believe you could remove that and still be OK.

Comment: The code `lines[sizelines] = malloc(50); lines[sizelines] = _strdup(s);` leaks memory.  Just use the `strdup()` line.

Comment: Suggestion: `lines` contains 100 char pointers, and you only ever allocate a maximum of 50 chars for each of those. This is not a prohibitive amount of memory to allocate on the stack with `char lines[100][50];` and doing so would eliminate one level of complexity from this code.

Comment: @Chris If I try to do this Im getting the following exception : Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'lines' was corrupted.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes you're right, accidentally copied it

Comment: @AllanWind But strcmp("<Name>", lines[i], 6)==0) should work right? It also doesnt output anything when trying. Removed the winsock2 header as im not using it

Comment: "If I try to do this Im getting the following exception" So 100x50 is probably not enough. Why do you think allocating the same exact amount of memory on the heap would be enough?

Comment: There are many, many, many things wrong with your code but I want to bring your attention to just one thing. Why do you need to read the entire file before processing the first line? Wouldn't it be about a zillion times easier to read a line, process it, then read the next line? No pointers, no arrays of pointers, no dynamic allocations, no nothing.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Ive tried using ´´´´if (strcmp(s, "<Name>", 6) == 0)´´´ in the while loop, but it wouldnt print out anything

Comment: It doesn't look like this problem has anything to do with what I just said. `strcmp(s, "<Name>", 6)` is invalid because `strcmp` takes 2 arguments, not 3.

Comment: `strcmp()` will not work, if you want to match on a prefix use `strncmp()` and set the 3rd param (`n`) to the size your prefix.  For example: `char s[] = "<Name>"; strncmp(s, lines[i], strlen(s))`.

Comment: You are missing a `}` so your code doesn't compile.  `_strdup()` is not declared.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, hard-code the first part as it works (at least with the input provided).  For the 2nd part, you are parsing XML (badly), so I would suggest you use an existing library (for example libxml2 at least on Linux).  With that out of the way here is a working implementation using a function `value()` for the heavy lifting.  That way, if you choose, you could process this per line instead of all the input at once as suggested above:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// caller frees return value
char *value(const char *line, const char *tag) {
    size_t tag_len = strlen(tag);
    char start_tag[tag_len + 2 + 1];
    sprintf(start_tag, "<%s>", tag);
    if(strncmp(start_tag, line, strlen(start_tag)))
        return NULL;
    const char *start_value = line + strlen(start_tag);
    char end_tag[tag_len + 3 + 1];
    sprintf(end_tag, "</%s>", tag);
    const char *end_value = strstr(line, end_tag);
    if(!end_value)
        return NULL; // end tag is missing or on different line
    return strndup(start_value, end_value - start_value);
}

int main() {
    const char *const lines[] = {
        "<Name>Peter</Name>",
        "<Name>Anna</Name>",
        "<Age>16</Age>",
        "<Pet>",
        "<Race>Dog</Race>",
        "<PetName>Lucky</Petname>",
        "</Pet>"
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(lines) / sizeof(*lines); i++) {
        char *target = value(lines[i], "Name");
        if(target) {
            printf("%s\n", target);
            free(target);
        }
    }
}
```

and the output:

```
Peter
Anna
```